# Calculate Private Proof-of-Authority TPS

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, scalability, proof-of-authority, poa

With a private Ethereum Proof-of-Authority network set up containing 3 sealer nodes, what can we do to estimate the TPS (Transactions per second) of the POA network?